# starting first activity from a child activity in TabGroupActivity in android

Tags: android

My application contains four tabs at the bottom.Each tab has multiple child activities.The flow may be like this,
    Tab1--A-->B-->C-->D-->E
    Tab2--X-->Y-->D-->E
    Tab3--M
    Tab4--P-->Q-->Y-->D-->E
      My question is ,
     when I am in C child activity of Tab1,and  I press Tab2.Again when I come back to Tab1 ,it is in C child activity.But I want A activity to be restarted.can someone please give  the solution by providing some sample code.Thank in advance

Comment: Try to override the onPause of your TabGroupActivity and call a intent  to A activity.

Answer (score 0):

from your B activity, start C activity using method, `startActivityForResult()` and Override `onActivityResult()` method in all of them this way.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    finish();
}
```

Now at every Tab switch, you must call finish() at current active activty. that in turn will destory all activities and coming back to that tab will show you first activity.

Note that, you wont want to destroy your first activty. For this reason, you must start activity B from A using `startActivity()` and you donot need to Override `onActivityResult()` for A activity.

regards,
Aqif Hamid